# Could someone explain this probability proof to me?

Tags: probability

> For a continuous random variable X, $X\sim EXP(\theta) \iff$ $P(X > a + t | X > a) = P(X > t)$
>
> Proof:
>
> $P(X > a + t | X > a) = \dfrac{P(X > a + t \cap X >a)}{P(X > a)}$
>
> $= \dfrac{P(X > a + t)}{P(X > a)}$
>
> $= \dfrac{e^{-(a+t)/\theta}}{e^{-a/\theta}}$
>
> $= P(X>t)$

Can someone explain to me why $P(X > a + t \cap X >a) = P(X > a + t)$

Comment: Just FYI, this is called memoryless property

Comment: You didn't say $t>0$, which is required for this step.

Comment: Well, I think my answer is at least more simply expressed than the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(X > a + t) \bigcap (X > a)$ means that the random variable $X$ is both greater than $a + t$ and also greater than $a$.  But, if $X > a + t$, then it is already greater than $a$.  So, that statement is equivalent to $X > a + t$.

A simpler statement that is similar would be $(X > 1) \bigcap (X > 0)$.  If $X > 1$, then we already know $X > 0$, so that extra statement doesn't add any new information.  So, here, this is equivalent to just $X > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because, if $t\geqslant0$, then $[X\gt a+t]\subseteq[X\gt a]$, hence 
$$
[X\gt a+t,X\gt a]=[X\gt a+t]\cap[X\gt a]\subseteq[X\gt a].$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ and $t$ are both positive, saying "$X>a+t$ and $X>a$" is the same as saying $X>a+t$.

For example saying the price of an item is more than $\$6$ and also more than $\$8$, is the same as saying it's more than $\$8$.